# Toggle (open/minimize) application on Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, keyboard-shortcuts, macbook, keyboard-layout

Example of behavior on Windows:

1. Open Chrome.
2. Click Chrome icon in task bar, Chrome is
   minimized.
3. Click Chrome icon in task bar, Chrome is opened again.

I want the same behavior on Mac. Is it possible?

Comment: No. Learn to use Spaces. You'll never need to minimise anything ever again.

Comment: @Tetsujin, what do you mean _use Spaces_?

Comment: See https://support.apple.com/kb/ph25574 It's far more powerful than messing around minimising & maximising things all the time.